# Hide modal window javascript

Tags: javascript, yii, hide, modal-dialog

So to show this modal I have the following code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="openModal(); return false;">A button</button>
```

and the javascript for this is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function openModal(a)   
    {
        $.modal({
            content:  'Some content here',
            title: 'a title',
            maxWidth: 500,

        });
        win.closeModal();
    }

</script>
```

I need a function that will hide this. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do the hideModal() function which will hide the modal when I click anywhere on the screen?

Comment: I am using Yii framework. On their documentation on modal widows, when created, the $.modal keeps the construction of the modal, like content, title, width, draggable, resizable, border, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dumb...

I fixed this with display none in css... It turns out I didn't thick it trough... I added the display none and a JS event that triggers the CSS upon clicking anywhere else in the page, except the modal.

Thank you very much for all your input guys! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

With the modal open in the browser window, use the browser's console to try

```
  var modal;
    function btnsModal() {
        var btns = {
            'Close': function (win) {
                modal.closeModal()
            }
        }
        return btns;
    }

    function openModal(oLink, content) {
        var btn = btnsModal();
        modal = $.modal({
            buttons: btn
        });
    }
```

Comment: tried and nothing... can you give me an example of js function that will hide the pop-up modal on call?

Comment: when i call the function to show the modal it works. I can add a button to close it that's not hard... The hard part is to make a function that on call will hide the modal.

Comment: ReferenceError: win is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

win.closeModal(); this is the error message from the console

but win.closeModal() is defined in the function so it won't hide the window

Comment: Also, it does put a close btn to the modal, but what i was asking about, was a hide function that when i click anywhere on the screen it will hide the modal

Answer (score 0):

You can add "open" event to dialog, and then bind on click listener to it which will close the dialog if you click anywhere---

```
open: function(){
        jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
            jQuery('#ID_of_ur_dialog').dialog('close');
        })
    }
```

for hiding effect you can use "hide" option---

```
hide: "highlight"
```